# scroll to first ng-repeat element in protractor and click

Tags: protractor

scroll is at bottom of the page, and it shows this error when I try to click the first element:

> ERROR: ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible (Session info:
> chrome=63.0.3239.84) (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522913
> (36222509aa6e819815938cbf2709b4849735537c),platform=Linux
> 3.13.0-137-generic x86_64)

## Code

```
element(by.repeater('item in arr').row(1)).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to scroll on it using two ways, both are simply JavaScript and through the protractor method `browser.executeScript` you execute them and then you go on with your protractor code.

Be careful that, as all the protractor methods, even `executeScript` returns a promise so chain it properly.

The general solution, which I personally prefer, is to use the `scrollIntoView()` method.

```
browser.executeScript('document.querySelector("a selector of your element or of your ng-repeater block or whatever identifies your element").scrollIntoView()').then(() => element(by.repeater('item in arr').row(1)).click());
```

Your particular solution, which implies to scroll to the top of the page, is the `scrollTo()` method.

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0, 0);').then(() => element(by.repeater('item in arr').row(1)).click());
```